# $dynamic wpdb query in $wpdb->get_results not taking second OR value into account

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a sql query returning the average and count of results matching column values. The issue is that $wpdb results works but only fetches the result for the first value in the dynamic query. To test, I have had the query it is constructing echo'ed to the page and when querying the database with php myadmin it fetches the result correctly (returns bother employer_name possibilities).

Also, when hardcoding this static query into $wpdb->get_results it also works fine. However, when running through $wpdb->prepare, although it sanitises and echos out a seemingly identical query to the hardcoded query, the result does not take the second argument for employer_name into account and only searches for values matching the first value for employer name, not both.

$test sql below is the query manually written and this works and fetches results for both employer name values

```
$test_sql = "SELECT COUNT(salary),AVG(salary) FROM table_name WHERE city = 'city'
             AND pending <> 'pending' AND employer_name = 'employer_name' OR 
             employer_name = 'employer_name_two'";
```

This is the dynamic sql constructor for the above example. Although it echo's out the seemingly identical query it discounts the second value for employer_name and thus only fetches some of the values.

```
$dynamic_sql = "SELECT COUNT(salary),AVG(salary) FROM table_name WHERE 
                city = %s AND pending <> %s AND employer_name = %s OR employer_name = %s";

$safe_sql = $wpdb->prepare($dynamic_sql,array( $city_name, 'pending', $employer_name, 
            $employer_name_two));

$result = $wpdb->get_results($safe_sql);
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: you query is not correct, it must be `(employer_name = %s OR employer_name = %s)` to get both employees . but else i can't see the problem.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried both with and without brackets and also tried using IN ('value 1','value 2') but it only ever considers the first value.

Comment: keep the bracktes please, everything else is wring. You should try to enable general log and see what reaches the server. It could be a bug, but try to verify if the query is correct